# Android Horizontal Scrolling not working on Custom Class

Tags: android, scroll

Not really wanting anything fancy. I want to to have both vertical and horizontal scrolling on a TextView that is created inside my class (which extends from a layout). Neither of these are working and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong....

```
public SideView(Context context){
    super(context);

    this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(AuxData.SchemeAndMasterWidth,AuxData.BoardHeight));
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    CardData = new TextView(context);
    Stats = new TextView(context);
    CardData.setTypeface(AuxData.Normal);
    Stats.setTypeface(AuxData.Normal);

    CardData.setWidth(AuxData.SchemeAndMasterWidth);
    CardData.setHeight(TextHeight);
    CardData.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    CardData.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    CardData.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    CardData.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
    CardData.setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
    CardData.setBackgroundColor(AuxData.BlackColor);
    Stats.setWidth(AuxData.SchemeAndMasterWidth);
    Stats.setHeight(StatHeight);
    Stats.setBackgroundColor(AuxData.WhiteColor);   

    this.addView(CardData);
    this.addView(Stats);

}
```

Then I add the data with a button press:

```
public void setCard(CardView cview){
    Card = cview;
    CardData.setTextColor(AuxData.WhiteColor);
    CardData.setTextSize(30);       
    String text = "--------------aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa----------------aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa--------\n";
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
    CardData.append(text);
}
```

The text is added just fine, however there is no scrolling whatsoever....

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept searching on the internet. Addeded this lines and now it's working:

```
    CardData.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    CardData.setMaxHeight(TextHeight);
    CardData.setMaxWidth(AuxData.SchemeAndMasterWidth)
```

My bars don't show but I don't really care about that...